# Want to Delete and Insert in same Action

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have one action in my controller that upload csv file with list of numbers.
Now the process is first I need to delete existing data from the table on certain condition then insert fresh data.
My snippet code is as follows..

Controller:

```
@Transactional
    def uploadFile() {

        if(!params?.updateExisting){
            println "Going to call service to delete records"
            myService.deleteNumbers()

            def newList = Number.findAllByDeleted(false)
            println "NEW LS:"+newList
            //HERE I'm GETTING BLANK
        }

        def file = request.getFile("fileCsv")

        file.inputStream
        .splitEachLine(',') { fields ->
            Number.withNewTransaction {

                        def number = fields[0]?.toString().replaceAll(" ","").replaceAll("-","")
                        Number numberInstance = new Number()

                        def numberExist = Number.findAllByNumberAndDeleted(number, false)
                        //HERE NUMBER IS STILL EXIST 
                        if(!numberExist){
                            numberInstance.number = number
                            numberInstance.save(flush:true)
                            count++
                        }else{
                            println "Number exist: "+number
                        }
            }
        }
        redirect(uri:'/number/list')
    }
```

myService:

```
@Transactional
    def deleteNumbers(){
        Number.findAll().each {
            it.deleted = true
            it.save(flush: true)
        }
    }
```

After calling service method `deleteNumbers` I'm getting blank list `NEW LS:[]`, But then `def numberExist = Number.findAllByNumberAndDeleted(number, false)` returns me a number means already exist.

Thanks..

Comment: In deleteNumbers in your service should `number.findAll...` be `Number.findAll` ?

Comment: Maybe start by moving all your business logic into the Transactional service method & just use the controller to direct to it after removing the Transactional annotation, I doubt you'll need withNewTransaction when processing the csv either

Comment: you couldv'e used a single `executeUpdate()` in your service

Comment: looks like you are getting the Number instances inserted in the previous runs of your `eachLine()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing  Number.withNewTransaction closure. Your code should work..